# Can i connect an already created angular project with nodejs(express)

Tags: node.js, angular

I already created an angular website in which i have done routing and connected to firestore. but now i want a middleware connection because i want the values scanned by RFID scanner(Rasberry PI)to get stored in firestore.
So can i connect this angular project with node as per now or do i need to rebuild my app?

I already tried to connect using node js but when i am running the server the screen is blank and only title is displayed

------IN SERVER.js---------

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
// const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// const morgan = require('morgan');
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
// const cors = require('cors');
const request = require('request');

const app = express();

// app.use(cors());

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '3001';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on ${port}`));
```

-------IN DIST/index.html --------

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Miracle Bus Track</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you suggest which technology should I use for theft management scanner for a grocery store like https://mishipay.com/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'yes', as client side JS UIs are usually decoupled from backend and can be hosted wherever.

However, your specific issue sounds like a code/build issue that Stackoverflow won't be a good place to sort out. One thing I see is you don't reference a  tag anywhere for the angular javascript so you should start there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir but i didn't get what you meant by this " One thing I see is you don't reference a tag anywhere for the angular javascript so you should start there.". If possible could you go through my code from this link : https://github.com/YatogamiMikoto/Miracle_Bus_Record and tell me what the changes i would need to make.

Comment: I even tried to connect but  it seems <app-root> is not being loaded when i am trying to launch server hence only blank page is coming

Comment: You aren't using any <script> tag - this is required to run Angular, point to your JS app, etc

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the scenario you mentioned, I would like to suggest you some different approach to handle this.
I would suggest you to use Google Cloud function https://cloud.google.com/functions/  instead of creating your own nodejs server.
Cloud functions are serverless functions run on nodejs server.

I am suggest this because you are already using Firestore.
I am suggesting so e architectural changes in your project.
Google also provide IOT module. That may help you more to cuumunicate to your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion sir!